# CSS3 IE 11 background image not appearing works in chrome, edge, safari just not ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer

my css looks like this:

```
body {
    background: url(images/Gabrielheroimage3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    max-height: 700px;
    max-width: 1300px;

}
```

tried removing max-height and width but didn't help.  also tried background-image rather than background and that didn't help either.  I appreciate any suggestions!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

background-image: url(images/Gabrielheroimage3.jpg);

Comment: Thanks Kyle I tried background-image and that didn't work in fact that is how I had it originally :(

Answer (score 0):

the page having a problem was literally just a background image with navigation.  Took the background image out of the css file and add div img tag and styled it within html and it worked on IE and all the other browsers for that matter.